# cannot convert argument 2 from 'const BITMAPINFO *' to 'const BITMAPINFO *'

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

I downloaded this code from the internet and got the following compile error from Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017:

> Error    C2664   'HBITMAP CreateDIBSection(HDC,const BITMAPINFO *,UINT,void **,HANDLE,DWORD)':
>   cannot convert argument 2 from 'const BITMAPINFO *' to 'const BITMAPINFO *'

How do I solve this?

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER BitMapInfoHeader;
    RGBQUAD bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO;

char * abMyBitmap = new char[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 100 * 100 * 4]; // ?? todo check this
const BITMAPINFO * pBitMap = (BITMAPINFO*)abMyBitmap;

HBITMAP hBitmap;
VOID * pvBits;

hBitmap = CreateDIBSection( NULL, pBitMap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: / ?? todo check this - is this a comment, because it won't compile

Comment: Why are you defining your own BITMAPINFO? Didn't you get any warnings about duplicate struct definitions?

Comment: It is likely that your local definition of BITMAPINFO does not match that of the argument of CreateDIBSection, which you apparently don't provide. Depending on the compilation settings, the definitions of BITMAPINFO can differ.

Comment: Defining your own `BITMAPINFO` breaks the ODR rule is UB and no diagnostic required.  You are just lucky the compiler reported it. Solution remove your definition.

Comment: I now recall that the Windows header force structure packing to 2 bytes, which is non-standard and is enough to explain the incompatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are re-defining `BITMAPINFO`? It is already defined in `wingdi.h`. Remove your `typedef`, and your code will compile fine.

Comment: The Q is about the compilation issue. I do not care about the logic of the code. If the code is not working, it will be a different question.

Comment: @uneven_mark Allocating the `BITMAPINFO` and adjacent byte array in one go is common practice. ["A bitmap is packed when the bitmap array immediately follows the BITMAPINFO header."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfo)

Comment: @Botje Yes I just realized what the idea behind is. I am not actually familiar with the Windows APIs and didn't realize that it basically required a non-standard use.

Comment: If you remove the `typedef...BITMAPINFO;` alltogether as suggested by this answer, your code compiles fine and the question is answered...

Comment: Ok  thank you för yor help, problem solved. The error message was not very helpfull.

Comment: @enocknitti Then you can mark the answer as ACCEPTED. ;)